# How to get a value of a certain array parameter and put it in another array?

Tags: php, json

I have the following encoded JSON array

```
{
"canonList": [{
    "deviceId": "Device123",
    "deviceModel": "Model123",
    "mapList": [{
        "alarmStatus": true,
        "disabledEndDate": "2020-01-28T15:06:19",
        "lastUpdateDate": "2020-01-02T15:06:19",
        "ruleDesc": "this is a test description"
    }, {
        "alarmStatus": true,
        "disabledEndDate": "2020-01-28T15:06:19",
        "lastUpdateDate": "2020-01-02T15:06:19",
        "ruleDesc": "this is a test description 3"
    }, {
        "alarmStatus": true,
        "disabledEndDate": "2020-01-28T15:06:19",
        "lastUpdateDate": "2020-01-02T15:06:19",
        "ruleDesc": "this is a test description 2"
    }]
}, {
    "deviceId": "Device1234",
    "deviceModel": "Model1234",
    "mapList": {
        "alarmStatus": true,
        "disabledEndDate": "2020-01-28T15:06:19",
        "lastUpdateDate": "2020-01-02T15:06:19",
        "ruleDesc": "this is a test description 5"
    }
}],
"resultCode": 0,
"transactionId": "retrieve_1580400944"
}
```

I am trying to create an array of just all the values of `ruleDesc` but I am only getting a null value. The index of the value is dynamic. One thing certain is I need the value inside `ruleDesc` ...

I've used

```
$arrayName['canonList']['mapList']['ruleDesc']
```

but it's only getting the value of the first array.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract all the `mapList` entries first, which you can do with `array_column`. Then you need to check if the `maplist` value has a `ruleDesc` key, in which case you add that to your output; otherwise you merge all the `ruleDesc` from the `mapList` into the output:

```
$ruleDesc = array();
foreach (array_column($arrayName['canonList'], 'mapList') as $mList) {
    if (isset($mList['ruleDesc'])) {
        $ruleDesc[] = $mList['ruleDesc'];
    }
    else {
        $ruleDesc = array_merge($ruleDesc, array_column($mList, 'ruleDesc'));
    }
}
print_r($ruleDesc);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => this is a test description
    [1] => this is a test description 3
    [2] => this is a test description 2
    [3] => this is a test description 5
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/gIoSE)

Answer (score 1):

As I see you have 2 inner arrays inside your JSON object. The first one is `canonList` and the second one is `mapList` so you have to iterate over both of them and add needed values into the result array like this:

```
$ruleDescs = [];
foreach ($arrayName['cannonList'] as $cannon) {
    foreach ($cannon['mapList'] as $map) {
        $ruleDescs[] = $map['ruleDesc'];
    }
}
print_r($ruleDesc);
```